# Convert thread function to asyncio

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, python-asyncio

I need to get some prices for an external API, one by one for dozen of objects and it's like 2 or 3 seconds for each request so it can become pretty long.

I (kind of) knew how to do multithread in python, i implemented it and it works fine and it's pretty fast.

Then i've recently discovered asyncio and it seems it could be useful in my situation instead of opening several thread. 
So i tried to "convert" my multithread code to a code using asyncio, as you can see below, after reading some examples. 
But when `testOne` doesn't work and the error is `Task exception was never retrieved`. 
I cleaned the code for better understanding (let me know if you need more informations).

```
from threading import Thread
import asyncio


### ASYNC MULTI THREAD ####
def prixMulti(client, symbol, prix):                                                                           
    prix[symbol] = # API price request using client

def testMulti(client, sql):
    prix = {}
    objects = # Database request using sql
    listeThread = []
    for object in objects:
        listeThread.append(Thread(target=prixMulti, args=(client, object['name'], prix)))
    for t in listeThread:
        t.start()    
    for t in listeThread:
        t.join()
    print(prix)

#### ASYNC ONE THREAD ####
async def prixOne(client, symbol):
    return #same API price request using client

async def prixOneWait(client, symbol, prix):
    prix[symbol] = await prixOne(client, symbol)

def testOne(client, sql):
    prix = {}
    objects = # Database request using sql
    tasks = []
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    for object in objects: 
        tasks.append(loop.create_task(prixOneWait(client, prix, object['nom'] )))
    loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.wait(tasks))
    loop.close()
    print(prix)

# Some code to initialise client and sql 

testMulti(client, sql)
testOne(client, sql)
```

Comment: "same API price request" in `prixOne` doesn't sound quite right. You should be using an async API and `await` its result. In particular, you must not call blocking functions from an `async def`, and you almost certainly want to await something (or the function might as well be sync).

Comment: I can't change the API as it's an external one, is it possible to make it async ?!

Comment: You can't make an API async as a user of the API; it has to be designed and implemented as async from the ground up. The closest you can get is to use [`loop.run_in_executor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_in_executor) to hands off the function to a thread pool, but then you're again using threads under the hood, and don't get the benefits of asyncio. If you only have sync APIs, I'd recommend the [`concurrent.futures`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html) module, which has a thread pool and nice primitives to work with it.